# Best way to find the nearest UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to find the nearest possible subview. In my app, there are 7 `UIButton`s and having a `UILabel`s centered below with a margin of 20. It's not a subview.

**What do I want?** To find out the nearest label to a button with lesser efforts.

**What am I doing currently?** I am passing a UIButton in a function and calculating the possible distances from that button to all the labels. Then sorting the distances results in ascending and picking the first object to get the minimum distance and that should be my nearest label.

```
internal func findNearByLabel(withRespectToButton button: UIButton) -> UILabel? {

    var distance = Array<CGFloat>()
    var labels: Array<UILabel> = self.view.subViews(type: UILabel.self)

    labels.forEach { (label) in
        distance.append(self.distance(label.frame.origin, button.frame.origin))
    }

    if !distance.isEmpty {
        let sortedDistance = Array.init(distance).sorted()
        let minDistance = sortedDistance.first!
        let indexOfMinDistance = distance.index(of: minDistance)!
        return labels[indexOfMinDistance]
    }

    return nil
}

internal func distance(_ a: CGPoint, _ b: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
    let xDistance = a.x - b.x
    let yDistance = a.y - b.y
    return CGFloat(sqrt((xDistance * xDistance) + (yDistance * yDistance)))
}

extension UIView {
    func subViews<T : UIView>(type : T.Type) -> [T]{
        var all = [T]()
        for view in self.subviews {
            if let aView = view as? T{
                all.append(aView)
            }
        }
        return all
    }
}
```

**What is problem?** No problem, it works, but I want to check if this is the best solution or there can be improvements possible?

Comment: Agree with @Sulthan, actually I was thinking of https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ...

Comment: I could probably reduce your code in half just by using `flatMap` and `filter`. You should probably prefer `[CGFloat]` over `Array<CGFloat>` and use `let` instead of `var` when possible. The distance could be defined using an extension on `CGPoint.distance(to:)` and it should probably make use of the `hypot` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a few improvements using functional patterns.

```
// generic method, can be in a category
extension CGPoint {
    func distance(to point: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        // there is already a function for sqrt(x * x + y * y)
        return hypot(self.x - point.x, self.y - point.y)
    }
}

internal func findNearByLabel(withRespectToButton button: UIButton) -> UILabel? {
    // you don't really need the subViews method
    let labels = self.view.subviews.flatMap { $0 as? UILabel }
    // don't forget we got "map"
    let distances = labels.map { $0.frame.origin.distance(to: button.frame.origin) }

    // we zip both sequences into one, that way we don't have to worry about sorting two arrays
    let labelDistances = zip(labels, distances)
    // we don't need sorting just to get the minimum
    let closestLabel = labelDistances.min { $0.1 < $1.1 }

    return closestLabel?.0
}
```

Comment: This is the benefit of StackOverflow, I am not aware of this inbuilt functions which make this code refactored properly. Thanks, Sultan.

Comment: @HemangShah The functions I have used are rather common, even Java have `map` now :)

Comment: Yes, sultan, I am facing a small issue in the above question, I am thinking to prepare a separate question or ask it to you directly here? What would you suggest? **Question**: for one of the buttons the label is not correct for the rest they are correct. There are no changes, no problem I can find with the buttons, all the buttons are identical and this peace of code works well with other buttons so should not be a case.

Comment: @HemangShah Maybe the problem is the comparison of distances to the top left corner? Maybe you want to compare frame centers instead?